# Resolve property at runtime. C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties

I have some class which have some code

```
public IEnumerable<TypeOne> TypeOne
    {
        get
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                var col = db.Select<TypeOne>();
                if (col.Count > 0) return col;
            }
            return db2.TypeOne;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<TypeTwo> TypeTwo
    {
        get
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                var col = db.Select<TypeTwo>();
                if (col.Count > 0) return col;
            }
            return db2.TypeTwo;
        }
    }
```

So as You can see there is a lot of duplicated Code and there are same property name and item type of enumerable.
I want to call some property of object like "obj.MyProp". And MyProp must be resolved at runtime with some generic or non-generic method. Is it possible?

Comment: could you elaborate some more? what is `obj.MyProp`?

Comment: What you need is called `reflection`. Here's a tutorial: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/

Comment: What ORM mapper are you using?

Comment: Most of the above can be dealt with using generics already - the only thing that's not that simple are the calls to `db2`, though you may be able to refactor those.

Comment: This is just sample. Not real code but idea. Calls to db2 we can make using PropertyInfo, but before this i must handle call ty MyProp.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly incomplete answer but you'll get the general idea:

This is a scenario where you want generics.

```
public IEnumerable<t> TypeSomething
{
    get
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            t col = db.Select<t>();
            if (col.Count > 0) return col;
        }
        return GetDB<t>();
    }
}
```

You'd need to implement GetDB() to return the appropriate db for any given type, but that'd be a single switch (or you can use reflection to find it)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using generics:

```
public IEnumerable<TypeOne> TypeOne
{
    get { return GetTable<TypeOne>(); }
}

public IEnumerable<TypeTwo> TypeTwo
{
    get { return GetTable<TypeTwo>(); }
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetTable<T>()
{
    if (db != null)
    {
        var col = db.Select<T>();
        if (col.Count > 0) return col;
    }

    return db2.Select<T>();    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure any of this actually uses reflection? ...I could be wrong though

Comment: @MicahArmantrout - No, it isn't. He's just given it the same name as [an unrelated method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) that does involve reflection. Steven - musefan is right, [generics and reflection aren't the same in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173128.aspx). Their types are determined at compile time.

Comment: I agree ... its a generic and its reflection but they are not the same

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes  -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx

Comment: @musefan and Justin, you are right, of course. It was a silly mistake (fixed), made because I rushed my answer. Generics and reflection can be considered the opposite, in this situation. In general, you should try to prevent reflection. I also renamed `GetTypes<T>` to `GetTable<T>` to make the distinction clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The best is probably a generic method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> dbSelect<T>() //may need type constraints here
{
    return db != null
           ? db.Select<T>()
           : null;
}
public IEnumerable<TypeOne> TypeOne
{
    get { return dbSelect<TypeOne> ?? db2.TypeOne; }
}
public IEnumerable<TypeTwo> TypeTwo
{
    get { return dbSelect<TypeTwo>() ?? db2.TypeTwo; }
}
```

If your `db2` object has a generic `Select<T>`-type method like `db` does, it's even easier:

```
public IEnumerable<T> dbSelect<T>()
{
    return db != null
           ? db.Select<T>()
           : db2.Select<T>(); //or db2.GetEntities<T>() or db2.OfType<T> or whatever
}

//Later, in your main code...
var x = dbSelect<TypeOne>();
var y = dbSelect<TypeTwo>();
```

This will be type safe, **considerably** faster than reflection, and will work with Intellisense.

Comment: There are duplicated Properties. I want to resolve PropertyName at runtime without writing code like public IEnumerable<TypeOne> TypeOne
{
    get
    {
        return dbSelect<TypeOne> ?? db2.TypeOne;
    }
}

Comment: In that case you don't really need the properties. I'll edit.

Comment: i have some project with Linq queries, but i need to replace some datastore with another. Simplified code replacement is not interesting for me =). I want to try something new

Comment: There is wrong idea that you give. I want to resolve called property name.

Comment: I understand wanting to try something new, I really do. Reflection is fun, but this isn't the place for it. Using reflection for this will make your code more difficult to work with, and it will be a SIGNIFICANT performance hit. If your goal is to be the best coder you can be, I urge you not to use something like reflection where you don't need it.

Comment: Also, if you follow the pattern in the last code block, you only need one method. This will be exactly the same as using a single property, since properties are compiled into methods anyway.